# Getting a "object not subscriptable error", any ideas?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it so whichever number is picked from the list, only returns the rows in the CSV with the same number in the "Set" column.

Code:

```
set_list = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5]
set = random.choice(set_list)
print("set = " + str(set))
set = not(set)

with open('TFT Project CSV.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    csv_file = csv_file[csv_file["Set"] != set]
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

CSV

```
Champion,Set,Cost,Orgin/Element,Class
Aatrox,1,3,Blademaster,Demon
Aatrox,2,3,Light,Demon
Aatrox,4,4,Cultist,Vangaurd
Aatrox,4.5,4,Cultist,Vangaurd
Aatrox,5,1,Redeemed,Legionnaire
Aatrox,5.5,1,Redeemed,Legionnaire
Ahri,1,2,Wild,Sorcerer
Ahri,3,2,StarGuardian,Sorcerer
Ahri,3.5,2,StarGuardian,Sorcerer
Ahri,4,4,Spirit,Mage
Ahri,6.5,4,Syndicate,Arcanist
Akail,1,4,Ninja,Assassin
Akail,4,4,Ninja,Assassin
Akail,4.5,4,Ninja,Assassin
Akali,6,5,Syndicate,Assassin
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and give us the output you are receiving?

Comment: "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

This is the exact error im getting, however it still says this when i try to replace the variable 'set' with a string. im assuming the problem is because you cant use a variable, so i tried using a string and list but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should post the full traceback because it contains important information about the error.

In any case, you're trying to treat `csv_file` as a dictionary on line 8, when it isn't one (it's a file object). I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there.

Also, `set` is the name of a built-in function, so you're overwriting it when you assign to it. You should try and avoid doing so, because it may cause problems later.